# Parse string to int array - Getting warning "makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, pointers, casting, int, atoi

I need to make a function that takes in a string of numbers parses it to an array of individual ints, but I'm having trouble doing so. The struct that holds the array is set up as follows:

```
typedef struct intArray {
    int *numbers;
}
```

Let's say the string I need to parse is named numString and equals "8162".
I've already malloced for the struct (this instance named newIntArray) and for the numbers child it holds. I have also created an int named i. This is my current code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    newIntArray->numbers[i] = atoi(numString[i]);
    i++;
}
```

When I try this, I get a warning that I'm making a pointer from integer without a cast. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the whole function I have right now:

```
Int40 *stringToIntArray(char *numString) {
    int i = 0;
    struct intArray *newIntArray = malloc(sizeof(struct intArray));
    newIntArray->numbers = malloc(40 * sizeof(int));
    if (newIntArray == NULL || numString == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        newIntArray->numbers[i] = atoi(numString[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return newIntArray;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of str?

Comment: Have you included `stdlib.h` ?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. Don't describe your code, show it. There is too much guesswork

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think it will be difficult for the OP to do that as this is his first question. i.e. to give an MCVE.

Comment: @akshayk07 you've got a better idea of what he should do?

Comment: If he shows all his code, people will start downvoting saying that SO is not for homework or something, but that would be what he will do.

Comment: @akshayk07 not at all. They will down vote if he dumps his code and asks "my code does not work can  someone fix it for me", but if there is a [MCVE] and a reasonable question, nobody will downvote.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That's what happened to me in the beginning XD.

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: If numString has only one number then atoi(numString) will give the value. You are getting that warning becaue you are passing numString[i] to atoi(). atoi expects a char* argument but you are passing a char argument.

Comment: @akshayk07 Thanks for the help, it's not giving the expected output but it did remove the error. I want to debug it on my own so I can learn what's going wrong.

Also, could you explain why my code wasn't working before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `atoi` function expects a string, i.e. a `char *` pointing to a string, as its parameter.  What you're passing in is `numString[i]`, which is a single `char`.  That's where the error is coming from.

Since you want to convert individual digits, you can instead subtract `'0'` from each character.  Because the characters for 0-9 have consecutive character encodings, this results in a digit character being converted to the equivalent number.  For example, `'5' - '0'` results in `5`.

```
newIntArray->numbers[i] = numString[i] - '0';
```

Comment: I get it now, and I'm no longer receiving that error. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @EliottBrown Glad I could be of assitance.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.